# addChild only shows when I compile - as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

I have a very long script with a lot of elements being added to the stage.
when I compile everything shows up perfectly in flash.
But once I open the file or go to my browser to look at it, the addChild's are not being added. I am unsure why this is, is there a problem with how I am compiling.

I would post my script, but I don't feel there is anything wrong with it. as it is working in the compiler perfectly. 
Also I had it working in the browser and in the file without issues then all of a sudden it just stopped working.

I don't know if this is a cache issue but I cleared all of my browser history and data.

Comment: Very unspecific. Make tests. Comment all the code and then uncomment it bit by bit to catch the moment it stops working in browser. You can also use some kind of debug panel (you may use mine: https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/597ab9968172d48c4d76b0f1cf39014f1b0dd1b1/classes/ru/delimiter/utils/Log.as?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default ) to figure out the place where your script fails in browser.

Comment: Is this code loading any external assets (images videos?). I wonder if you have a silent error about _something_ not being found? in such a case then your program cannot proceed & would appear to be frozen..